# Filter HTTP headers and POST them in the body to the downstream destination

Tags: typescript, http, nginx, http-headers

Firstly, this is not me trying to get the headers from a XmlHttpRequest, etc. There are also unique elements to my solution, which means that I cannot put a server side page in the front of my solution.

Essentially the block level diagram of my solution is as follows:

[image]

I want to basically sniff the headers of the HTTP request to the NGINX server, and then POST them to the ./index.html route of the NGINX so that I can get them in my TypeScript code of my Angular application, an then use them for some initial calls to my REST services.

At present my nginx-custom.conf is as follows:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

[image]

I cannot make the call from the WebSeal happen more than once, and so in essence I am asking, how can I extract the headers within NGINX and then use it in a follow on proxy/pass-through to my current base root.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's not possible for nginx to set request headers and pass it to your angularjs applications.

What you can do is forward the request that is coming on nginx to backend server where you can store those headers and manage them.

Here your normal request is working as expected in addition to that you also create an mirror request that you forward to your backend server to store headers.

**Example -** Any request that matches this `^/my.url` regex is forward to 
 default backend`http://$my_java_web_server` along with mirror request to `http://my.test1.server:8080;` server.

```
location ~ ^/my.url {
  proxy_pass http://$my_java_web_server;
  proxy_set_header Host $my_java_web_server;
  ...

  post_action @post_for_first_mirroring;
  ...
}

location @post_for_first_mirroring {
  proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
  ...
  proxy_pass http://my.test1.server:8080;
}
```